# Linearlayout missing in inside other LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have two  `LinearLayout` like below structure.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/kanji"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/goi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp">

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the second `LinearLayout` (id=`goi`) is not showing as expected. I tried changing the top layout to `RelativeLayout` but it didn't work also.

Why is this occuring?

My actual code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/kanji"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="漢"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="漢字"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="left"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:text="漢字"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:gravity="left"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/green"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="100/140"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/goi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="漢"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="漢字"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="left"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:text="漢字"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:gravity="left"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="160dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/green"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:text="100/140"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please elaborate  your question more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Linearlayout missing in inside other LinearLayout

Your root **`LinearLayout`** hight is **`120dp`** and you have 2 child `LinearLayout` with same hight of   **`120dp`** so there is no space for second `LinearLayout` to visible

### Solution

Change your root **`LinearLayout`** hight to **`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`** it will work

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/kanji"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="漢"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="漢字"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:text="漢字"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/green"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="100/140"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/goi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="漢"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="漢字"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:text="漢字"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/green"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="100/140"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @EagerToLearn its happen some time my friend

Answer (score 3):

The parent LinearLayout has a height of 120px as does the first child of it. So the first child LinearLayout fills up all the height of the parent layout.

You can either increase the height of parent LinearLayout or make it "wrap_content" so it dynamically adjusts its height to the content it has.

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because your top layout has fixed height

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

update this into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 2):

The height of your parent LinearLayuot and child LinearLayouts is 120dp. You will need to change the height of child layouts to fit into the parent layout

Answer (score 1):

You can use the directive `<include></include>` but I would advise doing an implementation on constraint layout